# Does when logged in or out Google account affects the player.seekTo() when using youtube player api?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api

I am working on a project with a client who requires a custom video player using youtube player api. After work submission, he complains that being logged in or out his Google account affects the player.seekTo() as follow:

Client: "I am using youtube playlist to add videos and play it in a playlist, and change the start time of the video programmatically. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/s3ow4rv1/."

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player, playerCont, ini_fullscreen = false, i = 0, ti = [], done = false, ctime = true, play_time = 0, real_play_time;

const playlist = ["WCFCdxzFBa4"];
const startSeconds_arr = [26];
const endSeconds_arr = [100];

function openFullscreen(elem) {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    playerCont = $('#video-container')[0];
});

$(window).load(function(){
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        playerVars : {
            playlist: playlist.join(','),
            autoplay: 0, // Auto-play the video on load
            controls: 1, // Show pause/play buttons in player
            modestbranding: 1, // Hide the Youtube Logo
            fs: 1, // Hide the full screen button
            cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
            iv_load_policy: 3, // Hide the Video Annotations
            autohide: 0, // Hide video controls when playing
            playsinline: 1, // Plays inline
            rel: 0 // Shows related content from the same channel
        },
        events: {
            onStateChange: function(event) {
                var index = player.getPlaylistIndex();
                if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING){
                    if(!ini_fullscreen){
                        //openFullscreen(playerCont);
                        ini_fullscreen = true;
                    }
                    ctime = false;
                    real_play_time = player.getCurrentTime();
                    if(i != index || (i == playlist.length-1 && typeof ti[i] != 'undefined' && real_play_time == 0)){
                        for(var j = 0;j<ti.length;j++){
                            clearInterval(ti[j]);
                        }
                        i = index;
                        ti = [];
                        player.loadPlaylist(playlist, i,startSeconds_arr[i]);
                        done = true;
                    }
                    else if(!done && i < playlist.length){
                        player.seekTo(startSeconds_arr[i],true);
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
                else if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED){
                    ctime = false;
                }
                else if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING){
                    if(i < playlist.length){
                        ctime = true;
                        $('#indicate-track').html('Indicator: Video ('+(i+1)+') out of ('+playlist.length+')<br>');
                        real_play_time = player.getCurrentTime();
                        if(play_time != real_play_time){
                            play_time = Math.abs(Math.round(real_play_time - startSeconds_arr[i] - 0.0));
                        }
                        if(typeof ti[i] == 'undefined'){
                            ti[i] = setInterval(function(){
                                if(ctime){
                                    play_time += 0.5;
                                }
                                $('#indicate-time').html('Time Passing: '+Math.round(startSeconds_arr[i]+play_time)+' secs, ends at '+endSeconds_arr[i]+'<br>');
                                if(play_time >= (endSeconds_arr[i]-startSeconds_arr[i])){
                                    clearInterval(ti[i]);
                                    if(i < playlist.length-1){
                                        done = false;
                                        play_time = 0;
                                        player.nextVideo();
                                        i++;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        done = false;
                                        play_time = 0;
                                        player.stopVideo();
                                        i = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 500);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Client: "When I am logged into my Google account and try running this script, it always starts at 0. However, when I am logged out of my account or incognito mode, it starts at the time specified in the playlist. I am trying to figure out how being logged in/out of Google account is influencing this script, and anything I can do about it."

Meanwhile it works well with me in both cases logged in/out my google account. Therefore, I have advised him to clear his browser cache, disable browser cache or even reinstall his browser. But, he says that nothing is working to solve this issue and strongly believes that being logged in or out Google account affects the player.seekTo().

Please advise; does when logged in or out Google account affects the player.seekTo() when using youtube player api?